# Knockout js, mvc 5 project - bind client ViewModel to the controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Could you please help me with this. I'm successfully getting data from the server ViewModel. However when I try to save client ViewModel from the view to the Controller Save action. I'm getting empty ViewModel. In the sample what I'm using was used JavaScriptSerializer. However this is not recommended to use in ASP.NET Core MVC project since there are Newtonsoft extension. Could you please help me to adopt below code to work?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@{
     var data = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
}

@section scripts
{
     <script src="~/lib/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/knockout-mapping/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
     <script src="~/js/realtyvm.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        var realtyViewModel = new RealtyViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
        ko.applyBindings(realtyViewModel);
        });
     </script>
}

/* Realty Client ViewModel */

(function () {
RealtyViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/App/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.realtyViewModel != null)
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.realtyViewModel, {}, self);
            }
        });
    }

}
})();
```

This how looks controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        RealtyViewModel realtyViewModel = new RealtyViewModel();
        return View(realtyViewModel);
    }

    public JsonResult Save(RealtyViewModel realtyViewModel)
    {
        Realty realty = new Realty();
        realty.Title = realtyViewModel.Title;
        realty.Description = realtyViewModel.Description;
        realty.RealtyType = realtyViewModel.RealtyType;

        _repository.InsertRealty(realty);
        _repository.Save();

        realtyViewModel.MessageToClient = string.Format("{0} realty has been added to the database.", realty.Title);

        return Json(new { realtyViewModel });
    }
```

Update, I opened XHR request, here is details:

Request payload

```
{Id: 0, Title: "Te", Description: "te", RealtyType: "te", MessageToClient: null}
Description:"te" Id:0 MessageToClient:null RealtyType:"te" Title:"Te"
```

Response:

```
{"realtyViewModel":{"id":0,"title":null,"description":null,"realtyType":null,"messageToClient":" realty has been added to the database."}}
```

Comment: Could you show your controller code too?

Comment: Hi I've updated question and added controller actions.

Comment: The only difference I see between your and my code is that I use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, don't know if that should matter.

Comment: Please check the XHR request which is sent with for example Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab, just to be sure that your JSON data is there in the body, and all headers are correct.

Comment: Hi I checked XHR request, please find details in updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by specifying from where coming data, by adding [FromBody] to   post action.

```
    public JsonResult Save([FromBody]RealtyViewModel realtyViewModel)
    {
        Realty realty = new Realty();
        realty.Title = realtyViewModel.Title;
        realty.Description = realtyViewModel.Description;
        realty.RealtyType = realtyViewModel.RealtyType;

        _repository.InsertRealty(realty);
        _repository.Save();

        return Json(new { realtyViewModel });
    }
```